# Wrap abel within a composite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have `ScrolledComposite` which allows only vertical scrolling. (`heighthint = 400`).

Within this ScrolledComposite, I have another `CompositeA` (height may exceed 400 for scrolling) to store all other widgets.

I have a very long label (with `SWT.WRAP` enabled). But instead of wrapping, it is always showing in a single line. I want this label to wrap according to the width of its parent (`CompositeA`)

I forgot to add that this `CompositeA` is a 2 column `GridLayout` with `makeColumnsEqualWidth = true`.

Here is my code:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Display display = parent.getDisplay();

    toolkit = new FormToolkit(display);
    form = toolkit.createForm(parent);
    form.setText("ABC");

    Composite body = form.getBody();

    TableWrapLayout layout = new TableWrapLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    body.setLayout(layout);

    Label header1 = toolkit.createLabel(body, "ABC: ");
    Font font = new Font(display, "Arial", 11, SWT.BOLD);
    header1.setFont(font);

    Label header2 = toolkit.createLabel(body, "XYZ",
            SWT.WRAP);
    font = new Font(display, "Arial", 11, SWT.NONE);
    header2.setFont(font);

    TableWrapData wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL_GRAB);      
    header2.setLayoutData(wd);

    form.getBody().setBackground(
            form.getBody().getDisplay()
                    .getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));

    // Scrolled composite
    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(body, SWT.BORDER_SOLID
            | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    sc.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
    sc.setBackground(new Color(display, 50,255,155));


    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL); 
    wd.heightHint = 360;
    wd.colspan = 2;
    wd.grabHorizontal = false;
    sc.setLayoutData(wd);

    sc.setLayout(new TableWrapLayout());

    Composite innerComposite = toolkit.createComposite(sc);
    sc.setContent(innerComposite);

    innerComposite.setLayout(new TableWrapLayout());
    innerComposite.setBackground(new Color(display, 255,50,50));

    Section section = toolkit.createSection(innerComposite,
            Section.DESCRIPTION | Section.TITLE_BAR | Section.EXPANDED);
    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL);
    wd.maxWidth = 600; // don't want to hardcode this value

    section.setLayoutData(wd);
    section.setText("Section");
    section.setDescription("A not so long description......................");

    // Composite for Section
    Composite sectionClient = toolkit.createComposite(section);
    layout = new TableWrapLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
    sectionClient.setLayout(layout);

    toolkit.createButton(sectionClient, "Button 1", SWT.RADIO);

    Label rightDesc = toolkit
            .createLabel(
                    sectionClient,
                    "A very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long desc that needs wrapping",
                    SWT.WRAP);
    font = new Font(display, "Arial", 10, SWT.ITALIC);
    rightDesc.setFont(font);
    wd = new TableWrapData();
    wd.rowspan = 2;
    rightDesc.setLayoutData(wd);

    Combo comboDropDown = new Combo(sectionClient, SWT.DROP_DOWN
            | SWT.BORDER);
    comboDropDown.setText("DDL");
    comboDropDown.add("1");
    comboDropDown.add("2");
    comboDropDown.add("3");

    Label lineBreak = toolkit.createSeparator(sectionClient, SWT.SEPARATOR
            | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL);
    wd.colspan = 2;
    lineBreak.setLayoutData(wd);

    /***********************/

    toolkit.createButton(sectionClient, "Button 2", SWT.RADIO);

    Label rightDesc2 = toolkit
            .createLabel(
                    sectionClient,
                    "A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long desc that needs wrapping",
                    SWT.WRAP);
    font = new Font(display, "Arial", 10, SWT.ITALIC);
    rightDesc2.setFont(font);
    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL);
    wd.rowspan = 3;
    rightDesc2.setLayoutData(wd);

    toolkit.createLabel(sectionClient, "Desc",
            SWT.WRAP);
    toolkit.createText(sectionClient, "hello world", SWT.NONE);

    section.setClient(sectionClient);

    innerComposite.pack();

}
```

If you run it, you can see a green scrolledcomposite and a red composite. I want the red composite width to fill to the width of the scrolledcomposite relatively without hardcoding `maxWidth = 600`.

Comment: I think I had a similar issue, and I solved it using `FILL` for `horizontalAlignment` and `true` for `grabExcessHorizontalSpace` in the `GridData` of the label and the Composite that contained it. Hope this helps.

Comment: i think when i call `innerComposite.pack()` it will layout the label in a single line? But without `innerComposite.pack()` i will not be able to see the entire layout.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem here in my layout and found [this](http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch15lev1sec12.html) useful answer.

Because of 'it is a not bug, it is a feature' try this answer from comment #19 [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9866).

I use the following lines of code for my Label.

```
Label tip = new Label(shell, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER | SWT.LEFT);
final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.HORIZONTAL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 1, 1);
tip.setLayoutData(data);
tip.setText("Here stands my long, long and much more longer text...");
```

Comment: `new GridData(SWT.HORIZONTAL, ...)` look weird, `HORIZONTAL` is not one of the allowed constants according to the `GridData` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding SWT.WRAP when creating the Label. It worked for me.

```
Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.WRAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might remember this wrong, but I recall I had to re-layout the composite when the text changed. That made the text wrap.

Comment: Check Zoltán Ujhelyi's solution here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499349/layout-issue-autogrow-label-swt

Comment: the text did not change. is just that it is already a long text when it first display

Comment: And you do a layout after you display it first?

Comment: yes i did a layout for it. the problem is that I do not want to hardcode the width. I want it to automatically follow the ScrolledComposite. But I don't seems to be able to get the width of the SC. Keep returning 0.

Comment: Interesting. In solution i linked the chap is adding a layoutData setting to the label. Which you don't as i see.

Comment: Nope. You do actaully. Ignore me :)

Comment: well.. i have no problem if i did not add it into a scrolled composite. but once i add into a scrolledcomposite, i will have the problem that the label is in a single line if i did not specify the width. but i want things to be relative instead of hardcoded..

Answer (score 0):

It was surprisingly to understand that `TableWrapLayout` manager will not count on the composites that scrolls horizontally. To keep that layout on the `Form` toolkit should be used. I've just made an example of code what could be done taking above.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Display display = parent.getDisplay();

    toolkit = new FormToolkit(display);
    form = toolkit.createForm(parent);
    form.setText("ABC");

    Composite body = form.getBody();

    TableWrapLayout layout = new TableWrapLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    body.setLayout(layout);

    Label header1 = toolkit.createLabel(body, "ABC: ");
    Font font = new Font(display, "Arial", 11, SWT.BOLD);
    header1.setFont(font);

    Label header2 = toolkit.createLabel(body, "XYZ", SWT.WRAP);
    font = new Font(display, "Arial", 11, SWT.NONE);
    header2.setFont(font);

    TableWrapData wd = new TableWrapData();      
    header2.setLayoutData(wd);

    body.setBackground(body.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));

    // Scrolled composite
    Composite sc = toolkit.createComposite(body, SWT.BORDER_SOLID | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    sc.setBackground(new Color(display, 50,255,155));
    layout = new TableWrapLayout();    
    sc.setLayout(layout);

    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL_GRAB); 
    wd.heightHint = 360;
    wd.colspan = 2;
    sc.setLayoutData(wd);

    Composite innerComposite = toolkit.createComposite(sc);

    layout = new TableWrapLayout();
    innerComposite.setLayout(layout);
    innerComposite.setBackground(new Color(display, 255,50,50));

    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL_GRAB); 
    innerComposite.setLayoutData(wd);

    Section section = toolkit.createSection(innerComposite,
            Section.DESCRIPTION | Section.TITLE_BAR | Section.TWISTIE | Section.EXPANDED);

    section.setText("Section");
    section.setDescription("A not so long description......................");

    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL_GRAB);
    // wd.maxWidth = 600; // don't want to hardcode this value
    section.setLayoutData(wd);


    // Composite for Section
    Composite sectionClient = toolkit.createComposite(section);
    layout = new TableWrapLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    // layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
    sectionClient.setLayout(layout);
    section.setClient(sectionClient);

    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL_GRAB); 
    sectionClient.setLayoutData(wd);

    Label rightDesc = toolkit.createLabel(sectionClient,
                    "A very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long desc that needs wrapping",
                    SWT.WRAP);
    font = new Font(display, "Arial", 10, SWT.ITALIC);
    rightDesc.setFont(font);
    wd = new TableWrapData();
    wd.colspan = 2;
    rightDesc.setLayoutData(wd);

    Combo comboDropDown = new Combo(sectionClient, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.BORDER);
    comboDropDown.setText("DDL");
    comboDropDown.add("1");
    comboDropDown.add("2");
    comboDropDown.add("3");

    Label lineBreak = toolkit.createSeparator(sectionClient, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL_GRAB);
    lineBreak.setLayoutData(wd);
        //
        //    /***********************/
        //
    Button button1 = toolkit.createButton(sectionClient, "Button 1", SWT.RADIO);
      wd = new TableWrapData();
      wd.colspan = 2;
      button1.setLayoutData(wd);

    Button button2 = toolkit.createButton(sectionClient, "Button 2", SWT.RADIO);
      wd = new TableWrapData();
      wd.colspan = 2;
      button2.setLayoutData(wd);

    Label rightDesc2 = toolkit.createLabel(sectionClient,
                    "A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long desc that needs wrapping",
                    SWT.WRAP);
    font = new Font(display, "Arial", 10, SWT.ITALIC);
    rightDesc2.setFont(font);
    wd = new TableWrapData();
    wd.colspan = 2;
    rightDesc2.setLayoutData(wd);

    Label desc = toolkit.createLabel(sectionClient, "Desc:");
    Text hello = toolkit.createText(sectionClient, "hello world");
    wd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL_GRAB);
    hello.setLayoutData(wd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SWT.WRAP is not enough if you want to have the long text label to wrap. The label won't wrap its text by default if you don't specify the **widthHint** in the layout. This works for me:

```
Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.WRAP);
label.setText("very very long text....");
GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 1, 1);
gd.widthHint = 200;
label.setLayoutData(gd);
```