# How to wrap a swt label text

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to wrap this text automatically, but it doesn't wrap. I'm trying with the code below, not sure what's wrong with the code. This is

```
protected Control createContents(Composite parent){
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.WRAP);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.HORIZONTAL, SWT.TOP, false, false));

    Group group = new Group(composite, SWT.NONE);
    group.setText("my group");
    group.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    group.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
    Button button = new Button(group2,SWT.CHECK);
    GridData data = new GridData(SWT.HORIZONTAL, SWT.TOP, false, true, 1, 1);
    button.setLayoutData(data);

    Label label= new Label(group, SWT.WRAP);
    data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    label.setLayoutData(data);
    label.setText("my long text is very long, I need to wrap this very long text lalalalalalalalalalalalalala");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11772305/2670892

Comment: @greg-449 : It is wrapping when I set the width hint to certain number, but when I maximize the dialog still it is filling the horizontal space, with out SWT.HORIZONTAL it doesn't wrap.

Answer (score 5):

The composite's layoutdata also needs to have `grabExcessHorizontal` space set to true, i.e.:

```
composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.TOP, true, false));
```

I think the wrapping label and all of its parent composites need to have that.

By the way, the style-bit `SWT.WRAP` doesn't make sense for class Composite.