# Resizing label to fit content

Tags: java, swt

I am creating a widget, which will display a text followed by a progress bar. For this I create a `Composite`

```java
container = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
container.setLayoutData(layoutData);
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
```

To this I add a `Label`

```java
messageText = new Label(container, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER | SWT.CENTER);
messageText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
```

followed by a composite holding the progress bar:

```java
  final Composite progressContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.BORDER);
progressContainer
    .setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

This is the result:
[image]

What I would expect is the label to grow as to be able to contain the full text. I have been trying to follow the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499349/layout-issue-autogrow-label-swt) however, I must be missing something as I am not able to achieve the desired behavior.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridData` you have specified uses all the available horizontal space but the vertical space only uses the initial size calculated for the control.

To use all available vertical space use:

```java
messageText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

Note that you are also specifying that the `progressContainer` should also grab all available space - this is probably not what you want so you may need to change that as well. Possibly:

```java
progressContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
```

If you want the message text to resize when you change the text you need to call

```java
container.layout(true);
```

after setting the new text to force the sizes to be recalculated. Use your original `GridData` values.

Comment: These changes do give the label all the possible space, however this moves the progress bar down to the bottom. I would like the label to take the space it requires, but not more than that. This way the progress bar is always directly beneath the text.

Comment: Perhaps as a side note, the progressContaienr does not need to fill the space, I simply want it directly below the text

Comment: Then call `layout` after setting the new text - see updated answer.